# SQL command failed because :IO Error: Got minus one from a read call for Oracle 19c and Oracle 21C

Tags: oracle, ubuntu-16.04, oracle19c, oracle21c, ubuntu-21.04

While connecting to Oracle 19c and 21c (via Docker images) , getting the SQL command failed because :IO Error: Got minus one from a read call. Strange thing is, this is not happening in ubuntu 16. the issue comes only with the ubuntu 20.

So is the issue related to ubuntu 20 ? or the oracle needs to be configured differently for ubuntu 20 ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: ORACLE DB is not certified on Ubuntu, anything can happen... see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316074/i-tried-to-install-oracle-18c-on-ubuntu-20-04-how-to-configure-it

Comment: Oracle is only certified on Oracle Linux, Red Hat, and SuSE. If you want predictable/reliable results, use one of those. There's lots of people that have hacked an install onto Ubuntu, but you're seeing first-hand why that isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @pmdba. we had a requirement to test oracle on ubuntu.